# Salesforce Multi Tenant Object Storage detail

Tags: apex, soql, force.com

I want to verify the following internal storage mechanisms in salesforce storage architecture,

Standard Objects (Account, Lead, Contact etc ) - stored in separate table or single standard object table ?

Standard Object Custom Fields - separate table i assume

Custom Objects/Custom Object Fields - Separate table I assume

Index/Lookup Table - for indexed fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the most interesting sessions at Dreamforce is one that I attended about the platform and how it is built. Internally, Salesforce stores all of your data in one large table. In addition to that data table is a metadata table. Every row in the table has your org/tenant id. Here is a link to that session:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeysYua6ENs

Comment: This also makes for a great read if you are interested further in the internals: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture

Comment: thanks for the information, i have seen the talk & read paper before, I'm looking for little bit more specific info to verify the above statements